# Chi Square Goodness of Fit or Kolmogorov–Smirnov test

Tags: distributions, chi-squared-test, binary-data, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I have a population binary data (2000 entries) as (pop_df):

```
ID   Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 ......Var100 Outcome
1     0    0    0     1  ...... 1       0
2     1    1    0     1  ...... 0       1
3     0    1    0     1  ...... 1       1
...
2000  0    0    0     1  ...... 1       1
```

and I have taken 500 samples from them (sample_df).

Then two check the sample_df is true representative of pop_df,
I did Kolmogorov–Smirnov test as mentioned below for Var1, Var2... Var100:

```
from scipy.stats import ks_2samp
x = pop_df['Var1'].values
y = sample_df['Var1'].values
ks_2samp(x, y)
```

*Questions:*

1. Is this test is suitable for checking if the sample (sample_df) comes from a population (pop_df) with same distribution (in the context of my data)?
2. Whether I also has to do Chi Square Goodness of Fit for this kind of binary data for deciding whether sample is true representative of population data (if there is a significant difference between the sample and the population with respect to input variables)?

   var rel_freq_of_vars_pop rel_freq_of_vars_sample
   var1 .23               .21
   var2 .50               .45
   ....

If I calculate the relative frequency of variables and do a chi_square test as below, is it sufficient to decide whether the distribution of frequencies of a variable in the sample was representative of the same variable in the population?

```
# Calcualtion of Chisquare
  chi_square = 0
  for i in range(len(df)):
      O = df.loc[i, 'rel_freq_of_vars_pop']
      E = df.loc[i, 'rel_freq_of_vars_samp']
      chi_square += (O-E)**2/E   
  if p_value <= alpha:
      conclusion = "Null Hypothesis is rejected."
```

**Update:**

```
Count data of Variable1:

Var1   Sample  Population
0        499     1998
1         1       2
```

*Which test is suitable if we consider one variable at a time (my current problem is some cells with a higher count value and other cells with a value less than 5?)*

Suppose for Variable 1, I do a chi-square test,
I get as mentioned below:

```
**Warning: Actual Value less than 5.
The results are not reliable.**

Chi-Squared Values:
0.000320385 0.0000800961
0.266667 0.0666667

Chi-Square = 0.333734

Degrees of Freedom = 1

p = 0.563469
```

Comment: The KS test is not applicable to discrete distributions.  You need to formulate a specific statement of what you might mean by "representative of:" could you clarify that?

Comment: to decide whether the distribution of frequencies of a variable in the sample was representative of the same variable in the population...

Comment: Which variable?  How you proceed depends on how many variables you want to check.  There are as many as $2^{100}$ possibilities in your case, which is too many, implying you have to limit your investigation.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the comment. If I have to check one variable at a time as I updated in my question just now...?

Comment: A chi-squared test will assess one variable at a time.  When assessing multiple variables you have to account for multiple comparisons.   Because that will degrade the power of your testing, it's important to think hard about which tests you really need to do.